# Mean of one column based on values of another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two columns `timeframe_change` and `timeframe_L`. I have the following code to calculate the mean when `timeframe_change` is less than zero:

```
df = test.groupby(['Code']).agg(
    Count=(timeframe_change, 'count'),
    Down_Mean=(timeframe_change,lambda x: x[x < 0].mean()))
```

If I wanted to instead calculate the mean for `timeframe_L` WHEN `timeframe_change` is less than zero, how can I reference the other column to calculate the mean?

Comment: Not sure what is your code but you can use `df.loc[df['timeframe_change']<0, 'timeframe_L'].mean()`

Comment: I added more context in the question mozway. Sorry for not including that earlier.

Comment: Thanks. It would be great to also provide a [mre] with the matching expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that actually did the trick. Thanks for all of your input.

```
LL_Up_Change=(timeframe_L, lambda x: x[df[timeframe_change] > 0].mean())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can index one column based on the values in another:

```py
df["timeframe_L"][df["timeframe_change"] < 0].mean()
```

Above `df["timeframe_change"] < 0` creates a `pd.Series` with `boolean` data type, which is used to mask the values in the data column `df["timeframe_L"]`.

**Edit after OP comments**

One solution would be to create a column with the filter you want and add this filter column to the `groupby`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "code": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"],
        "timeframe_change": [-1, -1, 0, 0, -1, -1],
        "timeframe_L": [11, 12, 13, 11, 12, 13],
    }
)
df['timeframe_change_lt0'] = df['timeframe_change'] < 0
df

>>> code    timeframe_change    timeframe_L     timeframe_change_lt0
0     A                   -1                11                  True
1     A                   -1                12                  True
2     A                    0                13                  False
3     B                    0                11                  False
4     B                   -1                12                  True
5     B                   -1                13                  True
```

Then grouping by both columns:

```py
df.groupby(["code", 'timeframe_change_lt0']).agg({"timeframe_L": "mean"})

>>>                                 timeframe_L
code    timeframe_change_lt0    
A                       False           13.0
                        True            11.5
B                       False           11.0
                        True            12.5
```

and then index the rows you require:

```py
g.loc[('A', True)]

>>> timeframe_L    11.5
```

**Edit 2**

You could also implement a custom aggregation function. The function should take the filtered data `pd.Series` as an argument and return the aggregation result. In the example below, the aggregated column is `timeframe_L` and this is `x` in the aggregation function. We can use the `index` on this series to index the other column and apply the mean as required. Note that the main `DataFrame` `df` must be in the scope of the aggregation function:

```py
def masked_mean(x: pd.Series):
    mask = df.timeframe_change.iloc[x.index] < 0
    return x[mask].mean()

df.groupby("code").agg({"timeframe_L": masked_mean})
>>>     timeframe_L
code    
   A           11.5
   B           12.5
```

Comment: I apologize as I failed to include the groupby.agg that is happening in the code. I have edited my initial code to show that. Would this work the same way in a groupby?

Comment: Confirmed that this did not work with the groupby.agg. Sorry, that was my fault for not originally including that part of the code.

Comment: @jrcart I updated my answer above, there may be a better solution but this should do what you want!

Comment: Thanks Paddy, but I'm not sure that fits into the current .agg. I was hoping I could use lambda is the same way I am using on the single column mean just having it check the other column; Down_Mean=(timeframe_L,lambda x: x[x > 0].mean())... where x=timeframe_change

Comment: @jrcart I've updated my answer here based on your comments (Edit 2)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access other columns in [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html). While you *could* access them using [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html) this would be inefficient.

Better filter your dataframe **before** aggregation, for example by creating a temporary column with only the negative values:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'Code': [1,1,2,2,3,3],
                     'timeframe_change': [1,2,3,4,5,6],
                     'timeframe_L': [1,1,1,-1,-2,-3],
                     })

df = (test
     .assign(timeframe_change2=test['timeframe_change'].where(test['timeframe_L'].lt(0)))
     .groupby(['Code'])
     .agg(Count=('timeframe_change', 'count'),
          Down_Mean=('timeframe_change2', 'mean'),
          )
      )
```

Output:

```
      Count  Down_Mean
Code                  
1         2        NaN
2         2        4.0
3         2        5.5
```

If you want to do this for all aggregations, then better or pre-filter (and optionally `reindex`):

```
df = (test
     .query('timeframe_L < 0')
     .groupby(['Code'])
     .agg(Count=('timeframe_change', 'count'),
          Down_Mean=('timeframe_change', 'mean'),
          )
      .reindex(test['Code'].unique())
      )
```

Output:

```
      Count  Down_Mean
Code                  
1       NaN        NaN
2       1.0        4.0
3       2.0        5.5
```